# Appropiate way to deal with "final" parameters in Objective-C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, final

I need to "translate" a `Java` class into `Objective-C`, and such class has a `private final` member and an initialization method which receives a `final` parameter:

```
public class MyClass implements ParentClass {
   private final OtherClass mOther;

   public MyClass(final OtherClass other) {
       this.mOther = other;
   }
}
```

What the best way to code an equivalent to this in `Objective-C` would be?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Another `final` parameter scenario I need to deal with: a method that is not an initializer and params are not being assigned to members of the class, they are only used in the method:

```
public List<ClassB> calculateSomething (final ClassA objectA) {
    // Some code and return sentence
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: Wouldn't that throw a compile-time error 'Variable mOther might not have been initialized' ?

Comment: @Shai not in Java, since each constructor (of which there is only one), sets `mOther`. I cannot speak for objective-c.

Comment: You're asking how to translate "final" in particular, or what's the essential part of this Java code for you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell In general... I'm not sure how I have to deal with both `final` things in this Java class, I don't know if I'd declare a `@property (readonly)` for the member, but then it seems that declaring the `final` parameter as `const` in `objective-c` is redundant...

Comment: You should find someone that actually knows Objective-C, rather than trying to get your Java code to compile as Objective-C and hope you've translated everything correctly...

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C has the equivalent of a `final` instance variable, where is is called `const` **except** that such a variable cannot be initialised in an `init` method.

*Before continuing you should ask yourself whether you should really be doing this at all. Should you really be trying to write Java in Objective-C, as opposed to writing code which accomplishes the same task in Objective-C? Ever noticed that a foreigner speaking your native-language can sound strange as they are speaking their own language but using your languages words? It's the same for programming languages - write Java in Java, Objective-C in Objective-C, etc.*

That said, sometimes a language just doesn't support something you'd like, or maybe it does...

**Warning: What follows can seriously damage your health!**

In C such things as types and const-ness are mere trifles which can be bypassed at will - this lackadaisical attitude is seen as a great feature by true believers, C programmers know what they are doing after all ;-)

What you are looking for in your case is the C ability to "cast-away const", that is to assign to a constant. (To be fair FORTRAN came up with idea originally, though not intentionally).

Here goes, first to make things a little easier a `typedef`:

```
typedef OtherClass *OtherClassRef;
```

This makes writing `const` declarations easier. Now the direct equivalent of your Java code:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
   const OtherClassRef mOther;
}

- (instancetype) init:(const OtherClassRef)other
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      // mOther = other; // Compile-time error: Read-only variable is not assignable

      // BUT in (Objective-)C(++) you can "cast-away const"

      *(OtherClassRef *)&mOther = *(OtherClassRef *)&other; // Yes it is ugly, which means nobody will do it by mistake!
   }
   return self;
}
```

Explanation:

1. `&` takes the address of the variable, the type of the result is "pointer to a constant `OtherClassRef`" - you *cannot* assign via this pointer as it is pointing at a constant.
2. `(OtherClassRef *)` is a cast to the type "pointer to an `OtherClassRef`", this is allowed and "casts-away" the const.
3. `*` in front of the cast, this is indirection and says to use the pointer to access whatever it points to for writing (lefthand side) or reading (righthand side).
4. The whole construction `*(OtherCLassRef *)&` is needed on both sides as both sides are `const` and to match they both need to be non-`const`.

That's it, **use sparingly**.

---

*Note 1: If you try this with other variable types, such as local variables, it may not (appear to) work.*

*Note 2: Some compilers may object to taking the address (`&`) of a `const` - Xcode/Clang does not.*

*Note 3: Drop the `typedef` and write out the declaration in full at your peril - C declaration syntax is the stuff of quiz questions!*

Answer (score 0):

My Objective-C is a bit rusty but it's something like this:

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) MyClass* mOther;
-(instancetype) initWithMyClass:(MyClass *) other;
@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass 
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, strong) MyClass* mOther;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(instancetype) initWithMyClass:(MyClass *) other{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        self.mOther = other;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Although I should say that there really is no exact equivalent for final in Objective-C. In Java, a final field can only be set in the constructor and it is immutable within the class. In Obejctive-C, at least as far as I know, the field is mutable within the class which means that there is a chance that the value could be changed if a developer isn't careful.

Comment: Thanks for replying. And if you don't make the property `readwrite` in the `.m`, and keep it `readonly`?